# If (Rvalue == LValue)

Tags: code-formatting

This is just out of curiosity I ask...

99% of the code I see anywhere, when using "IF", will be of the format "If (RValue == LValue) ...". Example:

```
If (variableABC == "Hello World") ...
```

There are other examples where I see the opposite:

```
If ("Hello World" == variableABC)
```

Anyone know how this started and why it's done?

Comment: Since what is happening here is an equality test, it doesn't really matter which value is on either side of `==`, since if `a == "b"` then `"b" == a` must also be true. I imagine the first scenario is done to prevent assignment when the you use `=` instead of `==` on accident.

Comment: These expressions are called "Yoda Expressions", see http://wiert.me/2010/05/25/yoda-conditions-from-stackoverflow-new-programming-jargon-you-coined/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is done because of this mistake in C and C++:

```
if (variableABC = "Hello World") ...
                ^
                (Watch here)
```

This way we have a compilation error:

```
if ("Hello World" = variableABC)
                  ^
                  (Watch here)
```

For example, C# and Java languages don't need this trick.

Comment: Amazing: before I am allowed to mark the answer, there's already 3 answers.

Answer (score 2):

The latter is done to prevent unintended assignments, if you, by mistake, use the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality operator `==`'

Some languages do not allow an assignment in an if-condition, in which case either is fine.

In languages that do accept assignments in if conditions, I always prefer going with the latter case.

Answer (score 1):

This is done because of the errors developers often do writing = instead of ==. In C++ integers can be treated as booleans and you got no errors at compile time.